# FacebookSDK gives 2 warnings in xcode6

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xcode6, facebook-sdk-4.0

I just update to Xcode 6 and now in the FacebookSDK.framework > Headers > FBOpenGraph.h I have 2 warnings one that reads

```
'atomic' attribute on property 'description' does not match the property inherited from NSObject
```

And the second reads

```
'copy' attribute on property 'description' does not match the property inherited from NSObject
```

Both these warnings on line line 69 in the code I have added a comment just above that line
This is the .h file I am taking about

```
    /*
 * Copyright 2010-present Facebook.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "FBGraphObject.h"

/*!
 @protocol

 @abstract
 The `FBOpenGraphObject` protocol is the base protocol for use in posting and retrieving Open Graph objects.
 It inherits from the `FBGraphObject` protocol; you may derive custome protocols from `FBOpenGraphObject` in order
 implement typed access to your application's custom objects.

 @discussion
 Represents an Open Graph custom object, to be used directly, or from which to
 derive custom action protocols with custom properties.
 */
@protocol FBOpenGraphObject<FBGraphObject>

/*!
 @property
 @abstract Typed access to the object's id
 */
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString              *id;

/*!
 @property
 @abstract Typed access to the object's type, which is a string in the form mynamespace:mytype
 */
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString              *type;

/*!
 @property
 @abstract Typed access to object's title
 */
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString              *title;

/*!
 @property
 @abstract Typed access to the object's image property
 */
@property (retain, nonatomic) id                    image;

/*!
 @property
 @abstract Typed access to the object's url property
 */
@property (retain, nonatomic) id                    url;

/*!
 @property
 @abstract Typed access to the object's description property
 */
 //*******************************************
//the line below this is where the warnings are
//&*********************************************
@property (retain, nonatomic) id                    description;

/*!
 @property
 @abstract Typed access to action's data, which is a dictionary of custom properties
 */
@property (retain, nonatomic) id<FBGraphObject>     data;

@end
```

I am also getting this error when I run my application not sure what it means either

```
registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: is not supported in iOS 8.0 and later.
```

[image]

Thanks for the help in advance!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem.

So I changed `description` to `copy`

And then `description` to `atomic`

And no more warnings, you could also try uploading a new Facebook.SDK as they might have changed it

No problem

Answer (score 5):

Updating Facebook SDK to newest version should resolve your issues, you are probably using old version whic is not ready for iOS 8 SDK

Download here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios

After you install new FB SDK, you should just Clean project and Build again without errors

Answer (score 2):

**I fixed the warning by just commenting out the property**.

These warnings are coming from FBOpenGraphObject.h.
If you check the line producing them you will see that the description attribute is anyway depreciated and that objectDescription shall be used.

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) id      Description __attribute__ ((deprecated("use objectDescription instead")));
```

I would suggest you just follow FB recommendation. Most likely you are not using this property anyway. In my case, Since I was not using it, commenting out the property removed the warnings.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, this is the best solution

Answer (score 1):

Go to ~/Library/Developer/Xcode and remove the whole contents of Xcode directory (Please be aware that there is some Xcode Archives there etc. so make sure you won't loose anything you need).

Comment: are you talking about in finder?

Comment: Yes, but the ~/Library folder is hidden by default.

Comment: when I'm in my finder and go macintosh HD I see library and developer nut then no Xcode

Comment: It is inside your user directory, so the path is /Users/<YOUR_USER_NAME>/Library - it is NOT the /Library directory at the top of your disk structure.

Comment: should I also remove the hidden files in there? Theres files called developer portal and folders called UserData should that all go? Ive added a screen shot of the folder

Comment: I removed everything, but you will loose Xcode settings and archives. But that fixed the same issue for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61588/discussion-between-iqueqiorio-and-czaku).

Answer (score 1):

just disabled this warning

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wproperty-attribute-mismatch" 
@property (retain,  atomic) id description __attribute__ ((deprecated("use objectDescription instead")));
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```